# Displaying count_all_results record to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble echoing a count to my view.

I'm using the count_all_results() function to return the number of subjects in a class.

Nothing shows in the view even though it works well when I test in the Controller

Model:

```
public function Gettotsubjects($session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select('subject_id');
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        $this->db->distinct();
        return $this->db->count_all_results('ftscores_primary');
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public function Gettotsubjects($session_id, $section_id, $class_id)
     {
    $data = $this->ftprimary_model->Gettotsubjects($session_id, $section_id, $class_id); 
    return $data->subject_id;
         
    }
```

View:

```
<?php echo $CI->Gettotsubjects($value->session_id, $value->section_id, $value->class_id);?>
```

Comment: are the values you send in the view file correct? did you try echoing them to see what they hold?

Comment: Yes. they are correct. But when I pass it to the view, it's blank

Comment: where does `ft_tot_score` come from?

Comment: Edited. sorry that should be 'subject_id'.

Comment: I think that return like is the cause. `count_all_results` should return you an integer. treating it like an object is probably causing it to return null or something. try returning `$data` by itself

Comment: Perfect! That is it. Thank you